# How to plot a boxplot grouped by the column names in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boxplot

my dataframe:

```
     Q   JJ    R    S   R'  S'    P    T   JJ    Q  ...    P    T   JJ    Q  \
0 -0.2  0.0  6.1 -1.0  0.0   0  0.6  2.1  0.0  0.0  ...  0.9  3.9 -0.3  0.0   
1 -0.6  0.0  7.2  0.0  0.0   0  0.4  1.5  0.0  0.0  ...  0.4  2.6 -0.5  0.0   
2  1.0  0.0  4.5 -2.8  0.0   0  0.3  2.5  0.8 -0.4  ...  0.4  3.4  0.9  0.0   
3  0.9  0.0  7.8 -0.7  0.0   0  1.1  1.9  0.1  0.0  ...  0.6  3.0  0.1  0.0   
4  0.0  0.0  5.2 -1.4  0.0   0  0.9  2.3  0.1  0.0  ... -0.2  2.9 -0.4  0.0   

      R    S   R'  S'    P    T  
0   9.0 -0.9  0.0   0  0.9  2.9  
1   8.5  0.0  0.0   0  0.2  2.1  
2   9.5 -2.4  0.0   0  0.3  3.4  
3  12.2 -2.2  0.0   0  0.4  2.6  
4  13.1 -3.6  0.0   0 -0.1  3.9
```

I'm trying to plot a boxplot grouped by the column names (there are 8 groups so I would expect 8 boxplots).
I used:

```
bp = df_net_wave_amplitude_for_std.plot.box(figsize=(20,8))
```

and

```
bp = df_net_wave_amplitude_for_std.boxplot(figsize=(20,8))
```

[image]
but I'm getting all of the columns in x-axis instead of getting them grouped by the name:

Comment: have you tried grouping the data first? would also rename your columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:
first i should have satcked the data:

```
df_net_wave_amplitude_for_std = df_net_wave_amplitude_for_std.stack()
```

then I arranged the result: reset the index, got rid of a redundant column (called 'level_0') and rename the colums:

```
df_net_wave_amplitude_for_std = df_net_wave_amplitude_for_std.reset_index()
del df_net_wave_amplitude_for_std['level_0']
df_net_wave_amplitude_for_std.columns = ['Wave', 'data']
```

and finally I could use the boxplot function:

```
bp = df_net_wave_amplitude_for_std.boxplot('data', by='Wave', figsize=(20,8))
```